# c++ stol throwing out of range exception for string length 10 or longer

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I am currently trying to convert a string of length 18 which represents a long integer into a long integer so that I can then do a multiplication with the string.  When I use stol to try to do the conversion, it runs into an out of range memory exception anytime the string length exceeds 10.  It works fine when the string length is less than 10.  Below is the relevant parts of my code:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    numbers[i] = numbers[i].substr(0, 10);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    n = stol(numbers[i].c_str());
```

Comment: Are you sure `long int` is more than 32 bits on your implementation?

Comment: That appears to be the problem.  I tried just assigning the value to n manually and it didn't work correctly.  I switched to a long long int and it worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This should depend on the implementation. For example, in GCC `long` and `int` are the same and on most machines are signed and 32 bits. This means that the largest number you can put there is 2147483647, that is, having 10 digits.

You should probably use `stoll` as its return type is `long long` -- 64 bits.

Answer (score 4):

A `long` only supports values between -2147483648 and 2147483647 inclusive. If you want to try using a `long long` instead then you'll need to use `stoll()`.

Comment: No, the lower limit can be -2147483647. And then that would be the minimal range.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure `long` is more than 32 bits on your implementation, in particular can represent that number?

While the standard does not mandate the exact range of the type, it only guarantees numbers in the range +/- 2147483647 will fit.
Anything more is at the discretion of the implementation.